# Angular, how to handle multiple observables used in template with the async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, observers

I have the following code

Template:

```
   <li *ngFor="let message of messages”>
    …
    …
       <img [src]="getThumbnail$(message) | async”>
   </li>
```

Component:

```
private thumbnails$: { [id: number]: Observable<string> } = {};

getThumbnail$(message: Message): Observable<string> {

  if (message.isImage && message.attachedFileId === undefined) {
    return of(this.getImageBase64(imageTiny));
  }

  if (message.gps && message.imageTiny === undefined) {
    return of(this.getPlaceHolderLocation());
  }

  if (this.thumbnails$[message.id] !== undefined) {
    return this.thumbnails$[message.id];
  }
  const thumbnail$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.getImageBase64(message.imageTiny));
  this.thumbnails$[message.id] = thumbnail$;

  this.loadImageAsync(message,thumbnail$); // this loads the big image and emits the result

  return thumbnail$;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to manage observables in a list.
The purpose of the map thumbnails$ here is to avoid to generate a new observable each time angular calls the method getThumbnail$.

Do I really need to keep myself the observables?

Can I "control" how and when angular calls this method?

Thanks

Comment: `messages` should be an observable. You don't need to have an observable in every oneof your array items ... Simply make the array an observable, and you'll manage a single observable.

Comment: Your code can be simplified and do not need to use BehaviorSubject. You can return   this.loadImageAsync(message,thumbnail$); directly from the method.